# Delay in touchpad & keyboard reactivation after screen energy saving: how to find out the problem?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad, thinkpad

I received a Thinkpad X1E4 with Ubuntu 20.04 and KDE/Plasma desktop, apparently installed with `sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop`.

The machine works pretty fine except for a little glitch: whenever the laptop goes into screen-saving mode (*not* sleep) for some minutes, upon reactivation of the screen the touchpad and keyboard are unresponsive for ~6 seconds, then they work normally again. Coming out of sleep does *not* show this little problem, nor does locking the screen.

I haven't found this same problem here on askubuntu, although I may have been searching for the wrong keywords ("keyboard delay" brings up answers about delay in key-repetition).

I wonder if you can help me in at least *diagnosing* the problem, if not in solving it. I'm a total Linux noob so I don't really know which logs or internal settings I should look at. This is a great chance to learn about the internals :) Cheers!